# Getting data from an array is undefined when using find function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't really know how to explain this so I will explain in code

```
const selectedId = props.match.params.id;
console.log(selectedId);
```

The above code prints the correct value for e.g if im on products/2 it prints 2, if I'm on products/3 it prints 3 and so on.

```
 const product = data.products.find((x) => x._id === 1);
 console.log(product);
```

Now I have a data array and I am using .find and as you can see x._id === 1, it prints the correct details for object 1 within the array.

```
 const selectedId = props.match.params.id;
 const product = data.products.find((x) => x._id === selectedId);
 console.log(product);
```

This prints undefined, if I had to console log selectedId it prints the correct id but when passing it through the find function it returns undefined.

Any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: the problem was that selectedId was a string whereas the id was an integer, and === would return false hence the undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely because the `_id` property is a *number*, but the `props.match.params.id` is a *string*. So comparing them with `===` will return false. Cast the param to a number before comparing:

`const selectedId = Number(props.match.params.id)`